# Jquery clone references to cloned element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, clone

I have an issue cloning an HTML element in JQuery :

```
var original = $('#malts-menus1');

var newID = "malts-menus" + malt_counter;
var clone = original.clone(true, true);

$('#malts-container').append(clone.prop('id', newID));

clone.children('.control-group').first().children('label').text('Malt ' + malt_counter);
clone.children('.control-group').first().children('.controls').first().attr('id', 'select0' + malt_counter);
```

This script is supposed to clone #malts-menus and append it to #malts-container

```
<div class="malts-container" id="malts-container">
  <div class="malts-menus" id="malts-menus1">
    <div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="select01">Malt 1</label>
      <div class="controls">
        <select name="malt" id="select01" 
                class="chzn-select malt-select">

          <c:forEach items="${maltList}" var="malt">
            <option value="${malt.getIng_Id()}">Malt
              ${malt.getMalt_cereale()} ${malt.getMalt_type()}
            </option>
          </c:forEach>

        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="select01">Quantité (kg)</label>
      <div class="controls">
        <input name="maltQte" class="input-xlarge focused"
               id="focusedInput" type="text" value="10">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="select01">Ajouter un malt</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-mini"
            onclick="addABlock(0);">+</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

... and it does. However, when I click the menu, the first menu opens instead of the selected one.

It looks like cloned element still refers to first element.

How can I clone and insert the new object as an independent object ?

Here I clicked on Malt 3 :

[image]

Comment: You're using a plugin for the dropdown, and it's still attached to the first one.

Comment: Also, on the last line, you aren't setting the select id correctly - you are setting the id on the div.

Comment: This is weird because before I copied the entire HTML code stored in a text variable) and it worked perfectly. I don't get why now I use clone() it still references to first element.

@Rhumborl right, I corrected this but still doesn't work. Id used to be the same even with multiple menus and it worked (I know, id should be unique)

Comment: I think you need to listen to the static container, instead of listening to the newly created object. New objects wont have a listener, but the unchanged container element may have one. `$('#staticContainer').on('click', '#yourNewlyCreatedSelectSelector', function() { ... });`. Could you also link us your current listeners to perhaps solve the problem faster? Or is it a plugin?